# How to find matching pairs with transitivity of equality in MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

If I have a table with data like this:

```
x1      y1      x2      y2

A001     1      B001    2
A001     1      B002    2
A002     2      A001    1
C001     2      B003    3
C002     1      B003    3
```

What would look like SQL query (Microsoft SQL server), to achieve result like this:

```
GroupId      x      y
1            A001   1
1            B001   2
1            B002   2
1            A002   2
2            C001   2
2            C002   1
2            B003   3
```

It's about grouping equal pairs like: if a == b and b == c then a == c

Comment: Grouping condition is not clear. You have x1,y1,x2,y2 columns, can you edit grouping accordingly?

Comment: The grouping table has different structure. It has GroupId which connects equal data, and x, y columns containing x1-y1 or x2-y2. This is like translating rows to columns

Comment: I dont get it. You should provide the grouping table to.

Comment: if you interpret each record as a line from x1/y1 to x2/y2, OP asks how to find the connected graphs (= GroupId) created by the lines.

Comment: That's right devio. That is the correct question.

Comment: do you need to check chains of elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after *some* trying I found the following:

```
DECLARE @mod int; SET @mod=1;
DECLARE @newgrp int; SET @newgrp=1;
CREATE TABLE tbl([x1] varchar(4), [y1] int, [x2] varchar(4), [y2] int);
INSERT INTO tbl
    ([x1], [y1], [x2], [y2])
          SELECT 'A001', 1, 'B001', 2  -- modified input to create chained equalities:
UNION ALL SELECT 'B001', 2, 'B002', 2  -- --> replaced A001 1 by B001 2
UNION ALL SELECT 'A002', 2, 'B002', 1  
UNION ALL SELECT 'C001', 2, 'B003', 3
UNION ALL SELECT 'C002', 1, 'B003', 3;

SELECT  x,y,0 grp INTO tmp FROM (
 SELECT x1 x,y1 y FROM tbl union SELECT x2 x, y2 y FROM tbl ) t;

-- set first seed: grp=1 on first ID only ...
UPDATE TOP(1) tmp SET grp=1;

-- now iteratively populate the tmp table 
WHILE @newgrp>0                         -- for each group
BEGIN 
 WHILE @mod>0 
  BEGIN                          -- in case of chained equalities
   UPDATE t2 SET grp=tmp.grp FROM tmp 
   INNER JOIN ( SELECT x1,x2 FROM tbl 
          UNION SELECT x2,x1 FROM tbl ) -- do group assignments in both directions!
              tt     ON tt.x1 = tmp.x AND tmp.grp>0
   INNER JOIN tmp t2 ON  t2.x = x2 AND t2.grp=0
   SET @mod=@@ROWCOUNT;
  END 
 -- OK, move on to the next group and then repeat the game ...
 UPDATE TOP(1) tmp SET grp=(SELECT MAX(grp) FROM tmp)+1 WHERE grp=0
 SELECT @newgrp=@@ROWCOUNT, @mod=1;
END

-- show the result
SELECT * FROM tmp
```

Result:

```
x    y   grp
---- --- ---
A001 1   1
A002 2   1
B001 2   1
B002 2   1
B003 3   2
C001 2   2
C002 1   2
```

The suggested sample script assumes that column y is not relevant for comparing (the sample data has for each x-value exactly one y value). If necessary it is of course possible to include the y columns into the comparison process.

**Edit:**

Et violá (the comparison now includes the y columns too):
**And ...** here is the **[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/932a9/2)** to go with it (I put in too many semicolons at first - silly me)!

```
CREATE TABLE tbl([x1] varchar(4), [y1] int, [x2] varchar(4), [y2] int);
INSERT INTO tbl
    (x1, y1, x2, y2)
          SELECT 'A001', 1, 'B001', 2
UNION ALL SELECT 'A001', 1, 'B002', 2
UNION ALL SELECT 'A002', 2, 'A001', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'D001', 3, 'B003', 3
UNION ALL SELECT 'D003', 1, 'D001', 3
UNION ALL SELECT 'D001', 1, 'A001', 1
UNION ALL SELECT 'C001', 2, 'B003', 3
UNION ALL SELECT 'C002', 1, 'B003', 3

-- start of processing ...

SELECT  x,y,0 grp INTO tmp FROM (
 SELECT x1 x,y1 y FROM tbl union SELECT x2 x, y2 y FROM tbl ) t;

DECLARE @mod int
SET @mod=1
DECLARE @newgrp int 
SET @newgrp=1

UPDATE TOP(1) tmp SET grp=1  -- set first grp-label (seed)

-- now iteratively populate the tmp table 
WHILE @newgrp>0                         -- for each group
BEGIN 
 WHILE @mod>0                           -- in case of chained equalities
 BEGIN
   UPDATE t2 SET grp=tmp.grp FROM tmp 
   INNER JOIN ( SELECT x1,y1,x2,y2 FROM tbl 
          UNION SELECT x2,y2,x1,y1 FROM tbl ) -- do group assignments in both directions!
              tt     ON tt.x1 = tmp.x AND tt.y1 = tmp.y AND tmp.grp>0
   INNER JOIN tmp t2 ON  t2.x = tt.x2 AND  t2.y = tt.y2 AND t2.grp=0
   SET @mod=@@ROWCOUNT
 -- OK, move on to the next group and then repeat the game ...
 END
 UPDATE TOP(1) tmp SET grp=(SELECT MAX(grp) FROM tmp)+1 WHERE grp=0
 SELECT @newgrp=@@ROWCOUNT, @mod=1
END

-- show the result
SELECT * FROM tmp
-- and drop tmp again
DROP TABLE tmp
```

I also added some sample data to show *chained equality* (`'D001' 3` = `'B003' 3` and
`'D003' 1` = `'D001' 3`) and to have cases with differing y-values (`'D001',1` and `'D001' 3`). The `while`loops caused me some head-ache since I did not pay enough attention to the contents of @@ROWCOUNT at first ... Now it should work again!

The chained equailty cases (recursion) were the main problem in this query. If they had not been, everything could be done in a single statement, see @Roman Pekar)

results of my (extended) example:

```
x       y    grp
------  ---  ----
A001    1    1
A002    2    1
B001    2    1
B002    2    1
B003    3    2
C001    2    2
C002    1    2
D001    1    1
D001    3    2
D003    1    2
```

Comment: Can you please include y column into the comparing process, because it is relevant for comparing. This seems to be correct answer, but I will have to test it after you edit script including y column. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need recursion, you can do it with [dense_rank()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) function:

```
;with cte1(x, y, xp, yp) as (
  select x1, y1, x2, y2 from Table1 union all
  select x2, y2, x1, y1 from Table1
), cte2 as (
  select
      x, y, xp, yp,
      case
          when x < xp then x + cast(y as nvarchar(max))
          else xp + cast(yp as nvarchar(max))
      end as grp
   from cte1  
)
select distinct
   x, y,
   dense_rank() over (order by grp) as grp
from cte2
order by grp, x, y
```

see [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aecbf/30) with example
hope that helps

**update** Actually it turns out it's easier to do it with table variable:

```
declare @Table2 table (x varchar(4), y int, grp int)
declare @Table3 table (x varchar(4), y int, xp varchar(4), yp int)
declare @i int = 1

insert into @Table2
select x, y, row_number() over (order by x, y) as grp
from
(
    select distinct x1, y1 from @Table1 union
    select distinct x2, y2 from @Table1
) as a(x, y)

insert into @Table3
select x1, y1, x2, y2 from @Table1 union
select x2, y2, x1, y1 from @Table1

while @i > 0
begin
    update T2 set
        grp = T4.grp
    from @Table2 as T2
        inner join @Table3 as T3 on T3.x = T2.x and T3.y = T2.y
        inner join @Table2 as T4 on T4.x = T3.xp and T4.y = T3.yp
    where T4.grp < T2.grp

    select @i = @@rowcount
end

select x, y, dense_rank() over (order by grp)
from @Table2
```

[**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f18b/5)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when additional rows are added like so. See Fiddle. Based on OP's question, I would expect to only see 2 groups. Your solution produces 5. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/25583/1

Comment: It's not doing chains - I've wrote about it in the answer

Comment: I could do more complex query later if OP need it

Comment: OK, I removed the chain between D002 and B003. I would expect to see at most 3 groups, but It still produces 5. Am I not seeing something? Just asking because I went down this road also and got stuck with this. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f18b/1

Comment: yep, my query is incorrect, thanks. I'll try to create better version

Comment: added new version. sry have no time to do something more elegant